# How to register a fall from height in unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

So i'm working on a 2D game, first stage is a platformer so i'm trying to make it look nicer. I added a particle system with dust, so in case he falls down from height animation should be played. How do i register a fall from height to play the animation?

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried and are struggling to get working.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 0):

You can play animation on [collision with the ground collider](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html), when player's falling velocity is higher than 0. Using specific positive value may be nicer, cos it's gonna look like only achieving enough speed will spread dust.

Answer (score 0):

I can see another way of doing this, but it takes more calculations:

To define the last position and current position of Y coordinates of the player.

If it is going down currentPos < lastPos
If it is going up   currentPos > lastPos

```
public GameObject player;
public GameObject particleDust;

Vector3 lastPos;
Vector3 currentPos;
float _time = 0;

private bool up = false;
private bool down = false;
private bool equal = false;

void Awake()
{
    lastPos = player.transform.position;
}

void Update()
{
    //assign player's position to current position
    currentPos = player.transform.position;


    //going up
    if (lastPos.y < currentPos.y)
    {
        up = true;
        down = false;
        equal = false;
    }
    //going down
    else if (lastPos.y > currentPos.y)
    {
        up = false;
        down = true;
        equal = false;
    }
    //same level
    else if (lastPos.y == currentPos.y)
    {
        equal = true;
    }


    if (down == true && equal == true)
    {
        particleDust.Play();
    }


    lastPos = currentPos;

}
```

You can define the up and down functions to define player's movement with bool.

When the direction down is True and lastPos = currentPos
then it means that he was going down and he stopped because the player hit the ground.

I choose this option without using colliders because it can be versatile and be used on every level without adding new things.

I assume this will work but it need more things, i hope this will get you started.

(If i said something wrong please correct me , it help me improve too, thank you!)

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking of how to detect falls from a specific height, I think this should work just fine in most cases:

```
private float startingHeight = 0.0f;
private bool grounded = true;
private bool landed = false;
//this is the distance the player needs to fall before dust shows up
private float fallingDist = 5.0f; 

private void Start()
{
    startingHeight = transform.position.y;
}

private void Update()
{
    if(grounded)    //set this to false when not colliding with the ground
    {
        startingHeight = transform.position.y;
    }
    else if(landed) //set this to true when hitting the ground while grounded is false
    {
        landed = false;

        if((startingHeight - transform.position.y) >= fallingDist)
        {
            //trigger dust particles or animation
        }
    }
}
```